# XPath get the siblings count only if node is present

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML which will contain the table information (column header and rows).

```
<Table> 
      <colHeading>name</colHeading>
      <colHeading>phoneNumber</colHeading>
      <colHeading>email</colHeading>
      <row>
          <col>jack</col>   
          <col>9123456352</col>
          <col>asd@abc.com</col>
      </row>
</Table>
```

I need to identify the phoneNumber value from the XML. 
The order/column names is dynamic so hard coded index values will not work. ie, first get the columHeading index where value is "phoneNumber" and pick the row/col[index] value. For this i have written an Xpath expression which is working fine and return the correct values if there is a phoneNumber column.

```
.//row/col[count(//colHeading[text() = 'phoneNumbr']/preceding-sibling::*)+1]/text()
```

Problem that i am facing is when there is no phoneNumber column it will always return the first row/col value as i am adding +1 to the preceding-sibling value.

how to handle this scenario in xpath. ie if "phoneNumber" is present then only i should identify the siblings and add 1. other wise it should return 0 as the index. Is there any functions in xpath which i can use to handle this scenario. I am using XPATH1.0.

Comment: so that if phoneNumber is not present row/col[0] will not return any values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the Boolean expression `../../colHeading='phoneNumbr'` to see if the column exists, and then make use of the type conversion rules - converting Boolean to number gives 0 for false and 1 for true.

```
.//row/col[count(../../colHeading[.='phoneNumbr']/preceding-sibling::*)
       + boolean(../../colHeading = 'phoneNumbr')]/text()
```

When there is no phoneNumbr column this will return an empty node set.

The use of `text()` inside the predicate is definitely redundant, the one on the end may or may not be depending exactly what you're doing with the resulting node set.

Comment: I tried this and is not working..condition boolean(../colHeading='phoneNumber') will always return false...also i am not sure how '+' works on a boolean

Comment: @Andromeda sorry, the path was wrong, it needs another `../`.  You could use `//` inside the predicate as you did originally, but I tend to prefer to localise my paths as much as possible, i.e. look at the col headings inside _this table_ rather than everywhere in the document (in this case those are both the same, but for efficiency it's good to stay away from `//` as much as you can).

Comment: @Andromeda and the `+` operator automatically converts its arguments to numbers, so `x + boolean` will be `x` for false and `x+1` for true.

Answer (score 1):

One possible *hack* to achieve that is by counting preceding-sibling starting from the next sibling of `<phoneNumber>`. This way you don't need to add `+1` :

```
//row/col[
       count(../../colHeading[. = 'phoneNumber']/following-sibling::*[1]/preceding-sibling::*)
    ]/text()
```

<s>Surprisingly,</s> this even work in the case where `<phoneNumber>` doesn't have following-sibling, like for example :

```
<Table> 
      <colHeading>name</colHeading>
      <colHeading>phoneNumber</colHeading>
      <row>
          <col>jack</col>   
          <col>9123456352</col>
      </row>
</Table>
```

Comment: not Surprisingly ....in this case tag row is a sibling for "colHeading"..and from there preceding-siblings will give the exact count :-)

Comment: @Andromeda you're right, was just too focus on `col`s and `colHeading`s maybe :D